# BigQuery - scheduled query through CLI

Tags: google-bigquery

Simple question regarding `bq` cli tool. I am fairly confident the answer is, as of the writing of this question, no, but may be wrong.

Is it possible to create a scheduled query (similar to seen in the screenshot below) using the `bq` cli tool?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, scheduled queries now could be created with `bq mk --transfer_config`. Please see examples below:

To create a scheduled query with query `SELECT 1`:

```
bq mk --transfer_config --target_dataset=mydataset --display_name='My Scheduled Query' --schedule='every 24 hours' --params='{"query":"SELECT 1","destination_table_name_template":"mytable","write_disposition":"WRITE_TRUNCATE"}' --data_source=scheduled_query
```

Note:

- `--target_dataset` is required.
- `--display_name` is required.
- In `--params` field, `query` is required and we only support [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) queries.
- In `--params` field, `destination_table_name_template` is optional for DML and DDL but required for regular `SELECT` queries.
- In `--params` field, `write_disposition` is same as `destination_table_name_template`, required for regular `SELECT` queries but optional for DML and DDL.
- `--data_source` needs to be always set to `scheduled_query` to create a scheduled query.

After a scheduled query is created successfully, you could expect a full resource name, for example:

```
Transfer configuration 'projects/<p>/locations/<l>/transferConfigs/5d1bec8c-0000-2e6a-a4eb-089e08248b78' successfully created.
```

To schedule a backfill  for this scheduled query, for example:

```
bq mk --transfer_run --start_time 2017-05-25T00:00:00Z --end_time 2017-05-25T00:00:00Z projects/<p>/locations/<l>/transferConfigs/5d1bec8c-0000-2e6a-a4eb-089e08248b78
```

Hope this helps! Thank you for using scheduled queries!

Comment: I am getting `BigQuery error in mk operation: Unknown data source 'scheduled_query'`

Comment: Probably scheduled query is not yet enabled on the project in use, could you try on the UI to enable scheduled query? Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I enabled the Data Transfer API, and it worked. Thanks so much. 
I am still trying to figure out why I cannot have the same from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/create or https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/66ab881/bigquery_datatransfer/samples/create_scheduled_query.py#L21-L72

Comment: Do you mean running into the same error even after enabling Data Transfer API while calling the API with API Explorer or using Python? Could you describe more of the error? (or please IM me for details)

Comment: Yes I run into the same error from the console, even after enabling Data Transfer API while calling the API with API Explorer